# Python 3. oneline if elif else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran in to this new syntax I haven't seen before...
Instead of writing:

```
foo = ""
if baa == 0: foo = "Heads"
else foo = "Tails"
```

I can write the whole thing on one line:

```
foo = "Heads" if bar == 0 else "Tails"
```

But in case if I want to choose between more than 2 values, is this the only way to achieve my goal ?

```
foo = "Paper" if bar == 0 else "Rock" if bar == 1 else "Scissors"
```

or is there a way to use "elif" in a way something similar to:

```
#the following line does not work
foo = "Paper" if bar == 0 "Rock" elif bar == 1 else "Scissors"
```

ps. Sorry I'm a noob with Python =)

Comment: I would use this shorthand `myvar = "foo" if CONDITION else "bar"` where there is a choice between two values. I wouldn't chain the `if` statement to much because the code can get ugly and unreadable really fast.

Comment: I'd use a dictionary `names = {0:'Paper', 1:'Rock', ... }` with `foo = names.get(val, 'DefaultName')` instead of the multiple `if`s.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and thanks to Martijn Pieters who linked this to an duplicate question that had a very comprehensive answer to this subject.